# Using ServiceClient in an optimal way

Tags: servicestack

I have a service that exposes a JSON-over-HTTP API (that uses ServiceStack) and now I am writing a .NET client (dll) that abstracts away this API to basically provide a domain-specific object abstraction on top of it. This client will be used by apps that need to hit the service a lot so striving for high-throughput and low-latency is important. I've done quite a bit of optimization work on the service to get it to acceptable levels of throughput and latency (measured those using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)). Naturally I would like to make the client as fast as possible.

I would like to use ServiceStack's ServiceClient library to handle the communication with the service and have a couple of questions:

- Is the JsonServiceClient thread safe?
- Does the JsonServiceClient (or any of the *ServiceClientBase children) do some sort of connection pooling when they talk to HTTP v1.1 servers? Or do they open a separate connection for each request they are asked to perform?

I would also appreciate any suggestions on how to use ServiceClient or perhaps maybe another library in order to make the communication with the service optimal (client-side caching is part of my plan so that's already in the works).